Powershell: How to process Result when the Result changes with every query?
I send a POST command against an API with Invoke-RestMethod. I expect the return value to be a download link that I want to process further. However, this URL is stored in a property whose name changes with each retrieval (in my Example 0bab6b8c-9f30-xxxx-xxxx-ad99957aeae0).
Example:
$query = Invoke-RestMethod @Params

Response:
$query.result.'0bab6b8c-9f30-xxxx-xxxx-ad99957aeae0' | fl *

status     : success
name       : myfile.wav
size       : 508312
source_url : https://xxxxxxxx/0bab6b8c-9f30-xxxx-xxxx-ad99957aeae0
duration   : 2

How do I get to the next property of $query.result with Powershell when I don't even know the ResponseID?

$query.result.PSObject.Properties.Value most likely. If the response was an IDictionary it would be easier, $query.result.Values

Answer depends on $query.result.GetType(), if the type is PSCustomObject then you can enumerate .PSObject.Properties.Value:
foreach ($object in $query.result.psobject.Properties.Value) {
    $object.name
    $object.source_url
    # etc
}

If the type is an IDictionary (Hashtable, Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, etc) then you can enumerate .Values:
foreach ($object in $query.result.Values) {
    $object.name
    $object.source_url
    # etc
}

